# Register user with mobile number problem in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want my user register in laravel application with mobile number and password
I edited my Register controller and my view but mobile value not sends to my table.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'mobile' doesn't have a default value
```

Here's my register controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/panel/code';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'mobile' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',

    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

and here's my view's code

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/auth/register') }}" class="col-lg-12">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" name="mobile" value="{{ old('mobile') }}" >
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label><i class="fa fa-envelope input-2-icon"></i><span class="span-input">شماره موبایل</span></label>

        @if($errors->has('mobile'))
            <span class="errr">{{ $errors->first('mobile') }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label><i class="fa fa-lock input-2-icon"></i><span class="span-input">گذرواژه</span></label>

        @if($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="errr"> {{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label><i class="fa fa-lock input-2-icon"></i><span class="span-input">تکرار گذرواژه</span></label>

        @if($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
            <span class="errr">{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="ccen2"><span>ثبت نام به منزله مطالعه و پذیرش <a href="http://pardakhtan.com/terms.html">قوانین و مقررات </a>است.</span></div>

    <button class="loginbutt">ثبت نام</button>
</form>
```

I do these steps but the mobile field not sends to my database.
what i do wrong?

Comment: Can you `dd($data['mobile']);` in your controller please? It might be that you are not getting the mobile value and you are trying to set the column mobile to null in your new row.

Comment: @party-ring it returns mobile number that get from view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to update the `$fillable` array in the `User` model to include `'mobile'` as well:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'mobile'
];
```

When you use `create`, Laravel will check to see if the provided fields are mass assignable. If a field is not mass assignable then Laravel will ignore it.

[Mass Assignment Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: I'm new to laravel 
Where i must define $fillable ?

Comment: @SinaMaafi In the `User` model (`app/User.php`). There will already be a `$fillable` array in there, you'll just need to add `'mobile'` to it.

Comment: Wouldn't it throw a MassAssignmentException instead of ignoring it?

Comment: @VistiK No, not in this case. The exception will only be thrown if the model is totally guarded.